# How to change order of integration in a double integral?

Tags: integration

How would you go about changing the order of integration in a function say ; $$\int_0^8\int_\sqrt[3]{y}^2 f(x,y)~dx~dy$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it helps to draw the region you are integrating over when trying to change the order of integration. For this case switching the integrals will give:

$\int_{0}^{8}\int_{\sqrt[3]{y}}^{2}f(x,y)dxdy=\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{x^{3}}f(x,y)dydx$.

Comment: ok but how did you get that.

Comment: The portion you are integrating over is between the graph of the the function $y=x^{3}$ the vertical line $x=2$ and the horizontal line $y=0$. When integrating over $x$ first we look at slits parallel to the $x$-axis of this region which are $\sqrt[3]{y}\le x\le2$ then we move $y$ from $0$ to $8$. If instead we look at the slits parallel to the $y$-axis then we see the region $0\le y\le x^{3}$ and we move this slit from $x=0$ to $x=2$.

Answer (score 20):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{8}\int_{\sqrt[3]{\vphantom{\large a}y\,}}^{2}{\rm f}\left(x, y\right)\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y
& = &
\int_{0}^{8}\left\lbrack\int_{0}^{2}\Theta\left(x - \sqrt[3]{\vphantom{\large a}y\,} \right)
{\rm f}\left(x, y\right)\,{\rm d}x\right\rbrack{\rm d}y
\\
& = &
\int_{0}^{2}\left\lbrack\int_{0}^{8}\Theta\left(x^{3} - y\right)
{\rm f}\left(x, y\right)\,{\rm d}y\right\rbrack{\rm d}x
\\
& = &
\int_{0}^{2}\left\lbrack\int_{0}^{x^{3}}
{\rm f}\left(x, y\right)\,{\rm d}y\right\rbrack{\rm d}x
\end{eqnarray*}

where Θ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

Comment: That was very, very nice and neat! :)

Comment: $\Theta (x-y^{1/3}) = \mathbb I (x,y)_{\{x>y^{1/3}\}}$ ?

Comment: @the-owner Yes. $\Theta$ is the $\texttt{Heaviside Step Function}$. Sometimes it's denoted as $\mathrm{H}$.

Answer (score 9):

The region of integration is the part of $[0,2]\times[0,8]$ where $x^3\ge y$:
$$
\int_0^8\int_{y^{1/3}}^2f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
=\int_0^2\int_0^{x^3}f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
The shaded region is where the integration takes place:

$\hspace{3.2cm}$[image]

The curve between the regions is $y=x^3$ or $x=y^{1/3}$.

Comment: right but how do you know that?

Comment: $y$ goes from $0$ to $8$. $x$ goes from $y^{1/3}$ to $2$. The minimum for $x$ is $0$ (when $y=0$) and the maximum of $x$ is $2$. Thus, all of the $(x,y)$ are in $[0,2]\times[0,8]$, but we also have the further constraint that $x\ge y^{1/3}$. You just read it off of the limits of integration.

Comment: By the way, is this the reason why $$\int_0^8\int_{y^{1/3}}^2f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y \neq
\int_0^8\int_0^{y^{1/3} }f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$

Since in the second case, $x^3 \leq y$?

Comment: Well, the integral on the left is for the shaded region, whereas the integral on the right is for the white region. Whether they are equal depends on $f$.