# Determining the limits of a Heaviside function

Tags: integration, limits

I asked a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2561088/53545) on using a Heaviside step function to change the order of integration. Now I need some help in understanding how the limits are determined, for example in this double integral:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1}^{e^y}f\left(x,y\right)\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y
& = &
\int_{0}^{1}\left\lbrack\int_{1}^{?}\Theta\left(e^y - x \right)
{\rm f}\left(x, y\right)\,{\rm d}x\right\rbrack{\rm d}y
\end{eqnarray*}

And what would the upper limit of the inner integral be? 
Is it $e$, since $0 \leq y \leq 1$, so that $\Theta(e^y - x) = 0$ from the interval $e$ to $\infty$?

---

My understanding: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1}^{e^y}f\left(x,y\right)\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y
& = &
\int_{0}^{1}\left\lbrack\int_{1}^{e}\Theta\left(e^y - x \right)
{\rm f}\left(x, y\right)\,{\rm d}x\right\rbrack{\rm d}y
\end{eqnarray*}

The bounds of the inner integral in the first step is $\{1 \leq x \leq e\}$, such that $e^y - x \geq 0$ on the interval $e^0$ to $e^1$. The interval is determined by the bounds of $y$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{1}\left\lbrack\int_{1}^{e}\Theta\left(e^y - x \right)
{\rm f}\left(x, y\right)\,{\rm d}x\right\rbrack{\rm d}y
& = &
\int_{1}^{e}\left\lbrack\int_{}^{}\Theta\left(e^y - x \right)
{\rm f}\left(x, y\right)\,{\rm d}y\right\rbrack{\rm d}x
\end{eqnarray*}

Fubini's Theorem.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{1}^{e}\left\lbrack\int_{}^{}\Theta\left(e^y - x \right)
{\rm f}\left(x, y\right)\,{\rm d}y\right\rbrack{\rm d}x
& = &
\int_{1}^{e}\left\lbrack\int_{\log{x}}^{1}\Theta\left(e^y - x \right)
{\rm f}\left(x, y\right)\,{\rm d}y\right\rbrack{\rm d}x
\end{eqnarray*}

The bounds for the inner integral is $\{\log{x} \leq y \leq 1\}$. Since $y$ is being varied, $y \geq \log{x}$, $0 \leq x \leq 1$. The upper bound for $y$ is 1 and the lower bound is $\log{x}$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{1}^{e}\left\lbrack\int_{\log{x}}^{1}\Theta\left(e^y - x \right)
{\rm f}\left(x, y\right)\,{\rm d}y\right\rbrack{\rm d}x
& = &
\int_{1}^{e}\int_{\log{x}}^{1}{\rm f}\left(x, y\right)\,{\rm d}y{\rm d}x
\end{eqnarray*}

Remove the Heaviside function.