# Changing integration order of $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{e^{y-1}}^{e^y} f(x,y)dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been trying to solve this question in many ways, at first I tried a graphical approach, which, didn't bring me many results, not any correct ones at least…
However, searching around, I found out about the "Heaviside function method", so this is my second attempt:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{e^{y-1}}^{e^y} f(x,y)dxdy=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1}^{e^y}f(x,y)dxdy+\int_{0}^{1}\int_{e^y-1}^{1}f(x,y)dxdy\\
=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1}^{e}\Theta (e^y-x)f(x,y)dxdy+\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1/e}^{1}\Theta (x-e^{y-1})f(x,y)dxdy\\
=\int_{1}^{e}\int_{0}^{1}\Theta (y-\ln(x))f(x,y)dydx+\int_{1/e}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\Theta (\ln(x)+1-y)f(x,y)dydx\\
=\int_{1}^{e}\int_{\ln(x)}^{1}f(x,y)dydx+\int_{1/e}^{1}\int_{0}^{\ln(x)+1}f(x,y)dydx
$$
The first part(first integral) seems to be right, the second, however, does not, can anyone please help me find my mistake? Is it in the boundaries?

I assume having a hard time figuring out how to calculate and adjust the boundaries to the Heaviside function ""conversion"", due to the lack of information I found about this part. After reading [this[link]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561180/determining-the-limits-of-a-heaviside-function?rq=1) I thought I had it figured out, but, after this result I'm not so sure anymore…

Comment: All is good, as far as I can see.

Comment: Hm… I've been using integral calculators to check my results, by doing $\int _0^1\:\int _{e^{y-1}}^1\:xdxdy-\int _{\frac{1}{e}}^1\:\int _0^{ln\left(x\right)+1}\:xdydx$ for example, in this case, could this just be a flawed method for answer checking? I mean, it seems to have been working so far, but, all the other functions were much simpler.

Comment: Now that I have looked more closely, are you sure of the order of integration? Since the inner limits are functions of $y$, shouldn't it be $dxdy$?

Comment: Oh, definitely, sorry, my mistake, I inverted it by accident when transcribing to LaTeX, the orders are correct on paper, and now, also on the question, thank you.