# Heaviside function - reversing order of integration when initial iterated integral is w/r/t dydx

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, self-learning

Refer to [this MSE example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/895457/1029325) where:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{8}\int_{\sqrt[3]{\vphantom{\large a}y\,}}^{2}{\rm f}\left(x, y\right)\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y
& = &
\int_{0}^{8}\left\lbrack\int_{0}^{2}\Theta\left(x - \sqrt[3]{\vphantom{\large a}y\,} \right)
{\rm f}\left(x, y\right)\,{\rm d}x\right\rbrack{\rm d}y
\\
& = &
\int_{0}^{2}\left\lbrack\int_{0}^{8}\Theta\left(x^{3} - y\right)
{\rm f}\left(x, y\right)\,{\rm d}y\right\rbrack{\rm d}x
\\
& = &
\int_{0}^{2}\left\lbrack\int_{0}^{x^{3}}
{\rm f}\left(x, y\right)\,{\rm d}y\right\rbrack{\rm d}x
\end{eqnarray*}

Is given as $\int\int_{R}f(x,y)\; dxdy$. I'm curious to know how order reversal would be done if it were $\int\int_{R}f(x,y)\; dydx$ instead - particularly when [the Heaviside function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) is given in terms of $x$:
$$\Theta(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr} 1 & x \geq 0 \\ 0 & x < 0 \end{array}\right.$$

I suspect you can make a similar definition in terms of $y$, by direct substitution:

$$\Theta(y) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr} 1 & y \geq 0 \\ 0 & y < 0 \end{array}\right.$$

and proceeding with similar manipulation as given in the example above, when given:

$$\int\int_{R}f(x,y)\; dydx$$

Can someone help me out? thanks

Edit: I suspect that when the reversal is $dydx\rightarrow\;dxdy$ it may require manipulation (taking the inverse) of an upper bound.