# The value of double integral $\int _0^1\int _0^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{x}{1+y^2}\:dx\,dy$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Given double integral is :

$$\int _0^1\int _0^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{x}{1+y^2}\:dx\,dy$$

---

My attempt :

We can't solve since variable $x$ can't remove by limits, but if we change order of integration, then

$$\int _0^1\int _0^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{x}{1+y^2}\:dy\,dx$$

$$\implies\int _0^1\int _0^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{x}{1+y^2}\:dy\,dx = \frac{1}{2}$$

---

> Can you explain in formal way, please?

---

---

Edit : This question was from competitive exam GATE. The link is given below on comments by Alex M. and Martin Sleziak(Thanks).

Comment: The first expression says that y goes from 0 to 1 (outer integral) which is ok and x goes from 0 to 1/x (inner integral) which makes no sense.

Comment: With $\int_0^x{\frac{x}{1+y^2}dx}$, do you mean $\int_0^x{\frac{s}{1+y^2}ds}$? Otherwise your variable of integration also appears in the interval over which you integrate...

Comment: Should the integral read as $\int _0^1\int _0^{\frac{1}{\color{red}{y}}}\frac{x}{1+y^2}dxdy$ or $\int _0^1\int _0^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{x}{1+y^2}d\color{red}{y}d\color{red}{x}$

Comment: Your problem contains a mistake, as Eric S. has pointed out: you cannot have $x$ *simultaneously* as an integration variable *and* as an integration endpoint, and yet this is what happens in your inner integral. As it is formulated now, your problem is meaningless.

Comment: Your bounds of integration don't make sense.  In the inside integral, $x$ goes from $0$ to${}\,\ldots\ldots\,{}$what? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: As the OP mentioned [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14150/2015/12/22), the problem was taken from [here](http://gateoverflow.in/610/gate1993_02-6). (It would probably be better to add this information to the question.)

Comment: Indeed, this is problem 2.6 of [the CS section of the 1993 GATE](http://gateforum.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/CS-1993.pdf). Remarkably, there is a very similar one (again, problem 2.6) in [the EC section of the 1993 GATE](http://gateforum.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/EC-1993.pdf) - this one having a lower integration bound of $x$ instead of $0$ in the inner integral. Both problems are mistaken, most probably it should have been $\Bbb d y \Bbb d x$ instead of $\Bbb d x \Bbb d y$, in which case it seems that the OP knows what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{x}{1+y^2}\space\text{d}x\text{d}y&=
\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{x}{1+y^2}\space\text{d}x\right)\text{d}y\\&=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{1+y^2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}}x\space\text{d}x\right)\text{d}y\\&=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\left[x^2\right]_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}}}{2\left(1+y^2\right)}\right)\text{d}y\\&=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2-0^2}{2\left(1+y^2\right)}\right)\text{d}y\\&=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}}{2\left(1+y^2\right)}\right)\text{d}y\\&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{2x^2(1+y^2)}\text{d}y\\&=\frac{1}{2x^2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+y^2}\text{d}y\\&=\frac{\left[\arctan(y)\right]_{0}^{1}}{2x^2}\\&=\frac{\arctan(1)-\arctan(0)}{2x^2}\\&=\frac{\frac{\pi}{4}-0}{2x^2}\\&=\frac{\frac{\pi}{4}}{2x^2}\\&=\frac{\pi}{8x^2}\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, we can't remove variable $x$ from given double integration.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay That's what I've showed you :)

Comment: I think Riemannian way: when we change $x$ the integral limits must be fixed :-) otherwise I can't use general integration rules, isn't it like that?

Comment: @Math-fun Yes it is!

Comment: then it seems like your Answer is mileading the OP.

Comment: Technically I think the answer is correct (at least up to the first expression without $dx$; I didn't check further). In a definite integral, $dx$ binds all occurrences of $x$ inside the integral, but not in the "start" and "stop" points of the integration, so $\int_0^{1/x} \frac{x}{1+y^2}\,dx = \int_0^{1/x} \frac{u}{1+y^2}\,du$.

Comment: As it is now, the question is mistaken and consequently so is this answer: you cannot have $x$ *simultaneously* as an integration variable *and* as an integration endpoint, yet this is what happens in the inner integral.

Comment: @AlexM.: as the question is written, this answer is correct. The $\frac1x$ in the limit of integration is not bound by the $x$ in the inner integration and is therefore free. That is, we can change the name of the inner variable of integration to get $$\int_0^1\int_0^{1/x}\frac{z}{1+y^2}\,\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}y$$ The question is written confusingly, but it is not "mistaken". However, the intended question may have been different.

Comment: @robjohn: See my latest comment under the original question (it is currently the last one there): the question comes from an exam, where it was given in this form presumably because of a typographical error.

Answer (score 1):

Right way is:
$$\int\limits_0^1x\:dx\int\limits_0^\dfrac1x \dfrac{dy}{1+y^2} = \int\limits_0^1\arctan y\:\Biggl.\Biggr|_0^{\dfrac1x} x\:dx =\int\limits_0^1x\arctan \dfrac1x\:dx = \int\limits_0^1\left(\dfrac{\pi}2-\arctan x\right)x\:dx =$$$$ \left.\dfrac{\pi}2\dfrac{x^2}2\right|_0^1 -\int\limits_0^1\arctan x\: d\dfrac{x^2}2 = \dfrac{\pi}4-\left.\dfrac{x^2}2\arctan x\right|_0^1 +{\dfrac12\int\limits_0^1\dfrac{x^2}{1+x^2}\:dx} =$$$$ \dfrac{\pi}4-\dfrac{\pi}8 + \dfrac12\int\limits_0^1\left(1 - \dfrac1{1+x^2}\right)dx = \dfrac{\pi}8+\left.\dfrac12(x-\arctan x)\right|_0^1=\dfrac12$$

To change order of integral, you build the region of integration in the chart, where you can see that the region of integration is made up of a square and curved trapezoid, so:
$$\int\limits_0^1x\:dx\int\limits_0^\dfrac1x \dfrac1{1+y^2}\:dy = \int\limits_0^1 \dfrac1{1+y^2}\:dy\int\limits_0^1 x\:dx +  \int\limits_1^\infty \dfrac1{1+y^2}\:dy\int\limits_0^\dfrac1y x\:dx = $$$$ \arctan y\:\Biggl.\Biggr|_0^1\cdot\left.\dfrac{x^2}2\right|_0^1 + \int\limits_1^\infty \left.\dfrac{x^2}2\right|_0^\dfrac1y\dfrac1{1+y^2}dy = \dfrac{\pi}8 + \dfrac12\int\limits_1^\infty \dfrac1{1+y^2}\dfrac1{y^2}\:dy = $$$$\dfrac{\pi}8+\dfrac12\int\limits_1^\infty \left(\dfrac1{y^2}-\dfrac1{1+y^2}\right)\:dy = \dfrac{\pi}8+\dfrac12\left(-\dfrac1y-\arctan y\right)\Biggr.\Biggr|_1^\infty = \dfrac12$$

And this way of calculation does not seem more simple.

Comment: How do you change order of integral?

Comment: I don't change it at all

Comment: I think the usual interpretation of $\iint f\,dx\,dy$ is that the inner integral is $\int f\,dx$. In this answer it seems to me the inner integral is taken to be $\int f\,dy$, a change in the order of integration.

Comment: Your formula for "changing the order of integration" is incorrect. You are leaving out a square $(x,y) \in[0,1]\times [0,1]$ which contributes a factor $\pi/8$.

Comment: That were intermediate calculations, sorry&thanks

Comment: @lcv It is easy to see, because the answer is known

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: As it is now, the question is mistaken and consequently so is this answer: you cannot have $x$ *simultaneously* as an integration variable *and* as an integration endpoint, yet this is what happens in the OP's inner integral. You have silently changed $\Bbb d x \Bbb d y$ into $\Bbb d y \Bbb d x$ right from the beginning, and this is why you don't encounter this problem, but in doing so you are not answering the original question.

Comment: @Alex M. Sorry, but I am not obliged to answer questions clearly erroneous.

Comment: @Alex M. There are two independent answers. The first doesn't use the change order of integral at all, the second accompanied by explanations...  I am waiting for an apology

Comment: The present situation is pretty funny: the OP asks a question that cannot be answered (because it is wrong), while you answer a question that nobody asked. Technically, this should be flagged as "not an answer" (even though from a mathematical point of view it is correct). What happened is that the OP asked a wrong question, you corrected it and then answered this new question. That's fine - but it not the OP's question. I suggest to wait for the OP to come up and clarify his question. In the meantime, note that the comment of David K. and the one of Eric S. have spotted the same mistake.

Comment: @Alex M I see that OP has a wrong attempt and asks to explain. So I try to show another ways. Is it funny?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { 1 }{ x }  }{ \frac { x }{ 1+{ y }^{ 2 } } dxdy }  } \\ =\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { 1 }{ x }  }{ \int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \frac { x }{ 1+{ y }^{ 2 } } dydx }  } \\ =\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { 1 }{ x }  }{ x\left( arctan1 \right) dx } \\ =\frac { \pi  }{ { 8x }^{ 2 } } $$

Now Mithlesh your method of approach is wrong as the limits of a multivariable integral are associated with the appropriate variable itself. You can not change the limits pertaining to a variable.

Comment: First, you have an upper bound of $\frac 1 2$ that the OP doesn't have. Second, instead of obtaining a number, you obtain a result that depends on $x$. Your answer simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AlexM. sorry for the typo

Comment: @AdityaKumar, you have changed order of integral :).

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay it is allowed to change the order of integral in multi-variable integrals.

Comment: AFAIK: yes, we can change, but limit should be also change.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay how can the limits be changed? It will change the answer completely.

Comment: @AdityaKumar, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467910/how-to-change-order-of-integration-in-a-double-integral

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33314/discussion-between-aditya-kumar-and-mithlesh-upadhyay).

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay view that carefully. The limit of the integral is associated with the other variable. Not the same one. Hence you can't change it. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467910/how-to-change-order-of-integration-in-a-double-integral. Here we can't do the same. There the limit of $y^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is associated with dx and not with dy. Hence you can change it at that case. Here the limit $\frac{1}{x}$ is associated with dx. Hence you can't do the same here.