# Switching order of integration on unbounded domain

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let's say ${f\left( {x,y} \right)}$ is a continuous function and assume that:

$\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\left| {f\left( {x,y} \right)} \right|dx} $ converges for all $y  $

2) $\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\left| {f\left( {x,y} \right)} \right|dy} $ converges for all $x $

Is the following statement correct?
$$\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {f\left( {x,y} \right)dxdy} }  = \int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {f\left( {x,y} \right)dydx} } $$

This is supposed to be some version of Fubini's or Tonelli's theorem but I wasn't able to find the exact version for this case.

Comment: It's not clear what follows "assume that:".

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to say they converge. I'll edit it

Comment: This can be treated as a corollary to normal integral switching in double integrals. By following that, you should see the limits don't change in this case (or do they? try and see). But in the case of only one unbounded, you could feel like you're in trouble. I suggest you consider a finite 'infinity' as they do I optical theory and follow this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6A44yQrGfU

related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467910/how-to-change-order-of-integration-in-a-double-integral

Answer (score 1):

I think the conclusion is false.

Let $g\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous non-negative function, such that
$g(x) = 0$ if $x\not\in [0,1]$, and $\int_0^1 g = 1$.
Let us consider the function
$$
f(x,y) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty [g(x-k) - g(x-k-1)] g(y-k),
\qquad (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2.
$$
Observe that, for every $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, at most one term of the series is different from $0$, and that assumptions 1) and 2) are satisfied.

Since, if $x\in [n, n+1]$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, one has
$$
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
g(x)g(y), & \text{if}\ n = 0,
\\
g(x-n)[g(y-n) - g(y-n-1)],
& \text{if}\ n\geq 1,
\end{cases}
$$
it is easy to see that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x,y)\, dy = 1.
$$
On the other hand, if $y\in[n,n+1]$,
$$
f(x,y) = [g(x-n) - g(x-n-1)] g(y-n),
$$
hence
$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x,y) dx = 0$ for every $y\in\mathbb{R}$, and
$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dy \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  f(x,y) dx = 0$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's something of a standard library of analysis counterexamples. Looking here... iterated integrals don't match, but the inner integrals are unconditional... OK, I've got it. Well, the version I have in memory is for sums: $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&\cdots\\-1&1&0&0&\cdots\\0&-1&1&0&\cdots\\0&0&-1&1&\cdots\\ \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\end{bmatrix}$

Sum along the rows first (inner) and we get $1$. Sum along the columns first and we get zero.

This can of course be converted into a version for the integral. Let
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1& 0<x-y<1\\ -1&-1<x-y<0\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
for $x,y\ge 0$. Then 
\begin{align*}\int_0^{\infty}f(x,y)\,dx &= \begin{cases}1-y& 0\le y\le 1\\ 0&y>1\end{cases}\\
\int_0^{\infty}f(x,y)\,dy &= \begin{cases}x-1& 0\le x\le 1\\ 0&x>1\end{cases}\end{align*}
so $\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy = \frac12$ and $\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}f(x,y)\,dy\,dx = -\frac12$. The order of the integral cannot be interchanged in general.

Now, quibbles. That's not continuous! No problem; just smooth the jumps out when defining $f$ - say, one period of a sawtooth wave $f(x,y)=g(x-y)$ where $g(t)=\begin{cases}t&-\frac12\le t\le \frac12\\1-t&\frac12\le t\le 1\\-1-t&-1\le t\le -\frac12\\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. Calculating the integral is a little messier, but we'll still get something positive for $\int_0^{\infty} f(x,y)\,dx$ when $y\in (0,1)$ and something negative for $\int_0^{\infty} f(x,y)\,dy$ when $x\in (0,1)$.
That's an integral on $[0,\infty)^2$, not $\mathbb{R}^2$! Padding the function with zeros when either variable is negative would do the trick - except that it disrupts continuity again. So then, we need to tweak it so that it's zero on the axes. OK - multiply $f$ by $\min\{x,y,1\}$. Working this out for my sawtooth example, it's a lot of calculation for not much benefit, so I'll just give the answer:
$$\int_0^{\infty} f(x,y)\,dx=\begin{cases}0& y\ge 2\\ \frac{(2-y)^3}{6}& \frac32\le y\le 2\\ \frac{y(\frac32-y)^2}{6}+\frac{5-3y}{24}& 1\le y\le \frac32\\ \frac y4 - \frac{3y-1}{24} - \frac{(2-y)(y-\frac12)^2}{6} & \frac12 \le y\le 1\\ \frac y4-\frac{y^3}{6}&0\le y\le \frac12\\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
All but one of those are clearly nonnegative; we simplify that third case to clear the last bit up:
\begin{align*}\frac y4 - \frac{3y-1}{24} - \frac{(2-y)(y-\frac12)^2}{6} &= \frac{4y-3y+1-4y^3+12y^2-9y+2}{24}\\
&= \frac{-4y^3 + 12y^2 - 8y + 1}{24}\\
&= \frac1{24}-\frac{y(1-y)(2-y)}{6}\\
\frac y4 - \frac{3y-1}{24} - \frac{(2-y)(y-\frac12)^2}{6} &\ge \frac1{24}-\frac{(1-y)(2-y)}{6}\ge 0\end{align*}
(The inequalities, of course, use that $\frac12 \le y\le 1$)
So then, $\int_0^{\infty} f(x,y)\,dx$ is always nonnegative. By the symmetry of $f$'s definition, $\int_0^{\infty} f(x,y)\,dy$ is always nonpositive, and the two iterated integrals are unequal.

This example runs on essentially the same principles as Rigel's already posted answer, but I find it a little clearer to work with the explicit piecewise definition than the fake infinite sum.